# Solr backup using SolrCloud

Tags: java, solrcloud

I would like to know that if I can take backup by using solrCloud in java.Will it take 1 shard as a backup?

what would be the correct procedure to take backup using java?

Answer (score 0):

For Solr Cloud you need to use the collections API.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API

Two commands to look at are:

- action=BACKUP: This command backs up Solr indexes and configurations.
- action=RESTORE: This command restores Solr indexes and configurations.

Comment: If you know the urls of a Solr instance (you can look them up with solrj) just do a normal http get call.